# Why is cordova.exec() running in my Android PhoneGap (1.7) app before "deviceready"?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying to "PhoneGap" (1.7.0) a jQuery Mobile app (1.1.0) I have to create an Android app. However, I keep getting the following alert message.

```
ERROR: Attempting to call cordova.exec() before 'deviceready'. Ignoring.
```

It *appears* as if this may happen during $.ajax calls, but it difficult to be sure.

I'm not making any calls to Cordova functions in my app - it's pure JQM.

Any ideas what the problem is. Or, failing that, does anyone know why cordova.exec() might be called during an $.ajax request?

I'm running the app under Android 4.0.3, in a virtual device/simulator.

Comment: Are you loading cordova-ver.js in your HTML?

Comment: Do you mean '<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script>', or is there a file named "cordova-ver.js, somewhere? If the former, then yes - it's loaded in my HTML.

Comment: Can you share a source snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Yeah, you are loading the script correctly. As Paul said, show some code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was having the similar issue after spending couple of hours i realized that cordova-1.7.0.js (or phonegap-1.7.0.js in your case) was of the iOS as originally i created project for iOS i replaced this file with the relevant android JS file and it started working.

The cordova-1.7.0.js is different for different mobile platforms, use the correct JS file for particular platform.

Comment: Doh! That was the problem. Forgot to update it when I moved from my iPhone testing to Android.

Comment: Yogesh!!! My savior!! :D Thank you so much for this! If you are ever in NY, I'll buy you a beer!

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because the

```
$(document).ready()...
```

function wasn't firing properly so i simply changed it to the javascript version

```
<body onload="init();">
```

in the html 
and defined a function

```
function init(){ 
     document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}
```

in my javascript file and it solved the problem